# What's the easiest way to view the contents of an SQL file / app data from an iPhone backup?

Tags: iphone, sql

I'm looking for an easy way to make sense of a SQL file that I've pulled from some application data in an iPhone backup. It's a huge file with bits and pieces of readable data strewn throughout, and right now I'm reduced to using a text editor to pick through it, which will take years.

Are there any simple SQL viewers available that would work for someone with limited technical knowledge? Or is there a way to export the contents of the file to a more easily readable format?

Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Base](http://menial.co.uk/software/base/), it is a paid app, but they have a free trial if you download outside of the Mac App Store. I use is daily for sqlite db's

Answer (score 0):

I use [SQLiteManager](https://sqlabs.com/sqlitemanager.php).

There are several other sqlite viewers, like [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/en/download/navicat-for-mysql), but I haven't used them personally.

Alternatively, you can just use sqlite on the command line:

```
sqlite3 path-to-file
.dump
.quit
```